# preventing cpu from going to 100% upon sys.exit python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio, sys

I have the code below that kills the script if the current audio device is disconnected.

```
    while True:
        if not(self.p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, device_id).get('name')):
            sys.exit("Audio device disconnected. Please reconnect!")
```

However, upon testing, I see that CPU usage still goes to 100% when killing the script. Is there a better or more efficient way to kill the script or check if audio device is disconnected?

Comment: I guess CPU usage is not 100% **upon** (i.e. after) sys.exit but **until** sys.exit.

Comment: Why not insert a call to `time.sleep(some_suitable_sleep_period)` in the loop so you are not continuously burning up the CPU?

Comment: With a `while True` loop like this you, the program will be continuously executing the code within the loop, probably causing the high usage you're seeing. As @Booboo said maybe try adding a `time.sleep(0.2)` or some other value you find reasonable (in seconds), so the loop isn't continuously running